# Getting error while sending email using Python

Tags: python, email

When I try sending an email from Python I get an error message. By the way I made less secure configuration and IMAP Enable on gmail account. Here is the code below:

```
import smtplib

sender_email="example@gmail.com"
receveir_email="example2@gmail.com"
password=input("please enter your password")
message="this email  from python "

server=smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smptp.gmail.com',587)

server.ehlo
server.starttls()
server.login(sender_email,password)
print("login success")
server.sendmail(sender_email,receveir_email,message)
print("email has been sent to",receveir_email)
server.close()
```

My error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/codebook/Training0718.py", line 23, in <module>
    server=smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smptp.gmail.com',465)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 1034, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 1040, in _get_socket
    new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: You have a typo in the SMTP host.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with the following, note that this will only succeed if you have created and are using an app password

```py
import smtplib


password = input('please enter your password')

to = 'example2@gmail.com'
_from = 'example@gmail.com'
message = 'hello'

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(_from, password)
    server.sendmail(_from, to, message)
    server.close()

except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Gmail smtp address is **"smtp.gmail.com"** not **"smptp.gmail.com"**.

Secondly, you have to choose whether you will use SSL or TLS, you can't do both.
If you choose SSL, you should use port 465 and remove:

```
server.starttls()
```

If you choose TLS, replace:

```
server=smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smptp.gmail.com',587)
```

By:

```
server=smtplib.SMTP('smptp.gmail.com',587)
```

Comment: Thank you i fixed it but still i am getting error like this

Comment: Thank you so much ,server=smtplib.SMTP('smptp.gmail.com',587) is  worked